# can not create express route connection via resource azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm

Could u please let me know if this is bug or I'm making a mistake?
I wanna to create an express route connection with a new subscription, if I'll go via Azure GUI console works fine but via terraform (apply stage) fail.
In the terraform plan (runs sucessfully), I see all input values correctly but I got this error below.
Does anyone know what is happening ?

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "express_route_circuit_connection" {
  name                = "az-prd-euw-expressrouteconn-001"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  type                            = "ExpressRoute"
  virtual_network_gateway_id      = azurerm_virtual_network_gateway.disaster_recovery_virtual_network_gateway.id
  peer_virtual_network_gateway_id = data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.express_route_circuit.id
  authorization_key               = azurerm_express_route_circuit_authorization.marel-disasterrecovery.authorization_key
  routing_weight                  = 1
}
```

**terraform plan stage**

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.disaster_recovery.azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection.express_route_circuit_connection will be created
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "express_route_circuit_connection" {
      + authorization_key                  = (sensitive value)
      + connection_mode                    = "Default"
      + connection_protocol                = (known after apply)
      + enable_bgp                         = (known after apply)
      + express_route_gateway_bypass       = (known after apply)
      + id                                 = (known after apply)
      + location                           = "westeurope"
      + name                               = "***********-expressrouteconn-001"
      + peer_virtual_network_gateway_id    = "/subscriptions/***********/resourceGroups/***********-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/***********-001"
      + resource_group_name                = "***********-rg-001"
      + routing_weight                     = 1
      + type                               = "ExpressRoute"
      + use_policy_based_traffic_selectors = (known after apply)
      + virtual_network_gateway_id         = "/subscriptions/***********/resourceGroups/***********-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/***********-vgw-001"
    }
```

**Follow the error messages:**

```
module.disaster_recovery.azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection.express_route_circuit_connection: Creating...
╷
│ Error: ID was missing the `virtualNetworkGateways` element
│
│   with module.disaster_recovery.azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection.express_route_circuit_connection,
│   on modules/disaster-recovery/network.tf line 118, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "express_route_circuit_connection":
│  118: resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection" "express_route_circuit_connection" {
│
```

Could u please help with this strange issue?
I really appreciate your help and time

Regards,

Comment: First good possibility for root cause here is outdated provider version in your root.

Comment: Hello Matt, I already using the provide latest provider version, I don't think so this is the root cause

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue ;

The type you are using is `ExpressRoute` and as you are using this you need to pass the [**`express_route_circuit_id`**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_gateway_connection#express_route_circuit_id) instead of [**`peer_virtual_network_gateway_id`**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_gateway_connection#peer_virtual_network_gateway_id) because it is used when the type is `Vnet2Vnet` .

For example:-

```
gateway_connection_type  = "ExpressRoute"
  express_route_circuit_id = var.express_route_circuit_id
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **HashiCorp Terraform Documentation**| [***azurerm_virtual_network_gateway_connection***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_gateway_connection#express_route_circuit_id) .
- **GitHub Repo**|[***terraform-azurerm-vpn-gateway***](https://github.com/kumarvna/terraform-azurerm-vpn-gateway/tree/v1.1.0/examples/expressroute) with module details by @*kumarvna* .